# to update a column details into base table 2 from column of staging table against the datails of column from base table 1

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

There's total of three tables involved. one header base table, one material
base table, one staging table.

I have created the staging table with 4 columns, the values will be
updated from csv uploaded, column 1 is batch_no, column 2 is for
attribute.
>header base table(h) has batch_no and batch_id
>material base table(m) has batch_id, attr_m (empty, to be updated)
>staging table(s) has batch_no and attr_s

```
create table he (BATCH_ID number, BATCH_NO varchar2(30));
create table me (a6 varchar2(30), BATCH_id number);
create table s (batch_no varchar2(30), att varchar2(30));
```

I want to take values from attr_s and update attr_m against batch_no. How do I do that?

Here's my code, please help me fix this code, it doesn't work

```
update me 
set a6 = (select att 
          from s where batch_no = (select he.batch_no 
                                   from he, s 
                                   where he.batch_no=s.batch_no))
```

error received:

> single row subquery return multiple rows.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not very helpful to us. We don't have your schema, we can't run your code, and frankly there's just too many things which might be wrong for us to take a guess. If you want us to give you a useful answer please provide **sufficient detail** so we can understand your situation. In this case some simple tables with basic input data and expected outcome would be super helpful.

Comment: ok.. here's the query I used to create and error received: single row subquery return multiple rows. 

create table he
(BATCH_ID number, 
BATCH_NO varchar2(30))

create table me
(a6 varchar2(30), 
BATCH_id number)

create table s
(batch_no varchar2(30), att varchar2(30))

update me
set a6= 
    (select att from s where batch_no=
        (select he.batch_no 
        from he, s
        where he.batch_no=s.batch_no))

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to add more details or clarifications. Comments are intended for, er, comments (things which can be deleted without removing any information from the thread). In particular they are bad for code because of the small font, poor formatting and lack of layout.

Answer (score 0):

> single row subquery return multiple rows

The update statement is applied to each individual row in ME. Therefore the assignment operation requires **one scalar value** to be returned from the subquery. Your subquery is returning multiple values, hence the error.

To fix this you need to further restrict the subquery so it returns one row for each row in ME. From your data model the only way to do this is with the BATCH_ID, like so:

```
update me 
set a6 = (select att 
          from s where batch_no = (select he.batch_no 
                                   from he, s 
                                   where he.batch_no=s.batch_no
                                   and he.batch_id = me.batch_id))
```

Such a solution will work providing that there is only **one record** in S which matches a given permutation of (`batch_no`, `batch_id`). As you have provided any sample data I can't verify that the above statement will actually solve your problem.